# The non-existence of one distribution

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

The problem is to prove that does not exists a distribution $u$  on $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\langle u, \varphi \rangle = \int e^{1/x^2} \varphi(x) \, dx, \hspace{0.9cm} \varphi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}),
$$

where $C^{\infty}_{c}((\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\})= \{ f: (\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \, ; \ f \ \  C^{\infty}, \, f \text{ has compact support in } \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\} \ \} $.

To prove this I need to find a sequence of functions $\varphi_n \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ with support contained in $\{ x; \, \frac{1}{n} \leq |x| \leq \frac{2}{n} \}$ satisfying $\varphi_n \rightarrow 0$ in $C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\langle u, \varphi_n \rangle \rightarrow + \infty$.

Comment: Well, what's the problem? Do you understand why finding these functions is enough to prove that? Can you find them, or do you have any ideas about what they should look like?

Comment: If I found these functions, then the problem is solved. My problem is to found these functions. I don't have any idea to found them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, no, the method of proof is slightly different. You don't need to find a sequence of test functions that converges to zero in $C^\infty_c(\Bbb R)$.

Suppose the contrary: there exists a distribution $u\in D'(\Bbb R)$ such that it's restriction on $\Bbb R^\ast$ is represented by $\exp(1/x^2)$. Then, by definition of distribution, we can fix a compact set $K=[0,2]$ and find constants $C_K$ and $p_K$ such that $$|\langle u,\phi\rangle| \le C_K \sup_{j\le p_K}\|\phi^{(j)}\|_\infty$$for any test function $\phi$ with support contained in $K$.

Now that hints to proceed:

1) take $$g(x)=\begin{cases}0,&|x|\ge 1,\\e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}},&|x|\le 1.\end{cases}$$
Prove that this is a test function. What is its support?

2) take $h_n(x) =  g\left(n\left(x-\frac{3}{2n}\right)\right)$. Find its support.

3) can you find a lower bound on $|\langle u,h_n\rangle| $? (hint: you're integrating a product of two continuous sign-constant functions) What's the type of dependence on $n$?

4) can you find an upper bound on $\sup_{j\le p_K}\|\phi^{(j)}\|_\infty$? What's the type of dependence on $n$?

5) conclusion.

If you have questions regarding any of the above, ask in comments.